# App is crashing in iOS 10 after force Quit App from device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[image]My app was working fine till iOS 9 and when iOS 10 launched, my app got crashed in iOS 10 devices.

Scenario:

> App is working fine when we open the app on device first time. No issues there in that case.
>
> When i force quit my app, from next launch onwards, app is crashing in my device. crash as soon as i open the app.

Error i got from crash log was, MenuCell.xib is missing in app bundle. Menu cell is one of my custom cell and i thought of removing that cell and adding new menu cell with Xcode 8.

Still the app got crashed. So i changed custom cell and load default cell for table view. At that time, another cell called AlbumCell is missing from bundle issue arised and app crashed. (Also app is crashed for custom AdView as well).

So, Issue is, when i force quit my app, entire app bundle got crashed and its not working after that.

If anyone faced similar kind of issue, please Reply to my query...
for past 4 days, i was banging my head to find this solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How can you tell that these things are missing?

Comment: its showing in my error console when app got crashed ...

Comment: Can you please share code of cellForRowAtIndexpath written in MenuViewController

Comment: If you look inside the .app package, can you see any files with the name MenuViewCell in the subfolders?

Comment: hi Phillip Mills, its still there in my bundle

Comment: hi Sanchit Kumar Singh, my cell for row at indexpath code is working fine .. as i mentioned earlier, my app is working fine and well until it is force quit .. so, issue is happening after force quitting my app.

Comment: So, not "missing in app bundle" but unable to load it.  Hmmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the fix for my issue . Need to handle memory management in my app. Lots of background tasks, Core data saving were done when the app is launched from quit mode. This cause out of memory issue and app got crashed with all mentioned issues.

Managed core data saving and reduced some background service calling. Finally my app is working as before.

Thanks for all who take interest to fix my issue.

Comment: yeah .. my project was almost 5 years old code. so, its having all kinds of old and new codes. This cause the issue.